# Why a letter "e" after %{VARIABLE}e

Tags: .htaccess

I have found a little htaccess to allow CORS:

```
SetEnvIf Origin ^(https://subdomain.domain.com)$ CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=$1
Header append Access-Control-Allow-Origin  %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN}e   env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN
Header merge  Vary "Origin"
```

But i don't understand why in the second lines there is the letter "e" after %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN}

I have found this htaccess example on a lot of sites, but nobody speak about that. Is it a "concatenation" ?

Thank for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as examples, it's useful to read the official documentation. In this case, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header explains everything about the `Header` directive, including that the value can include various special values beginning `%`, such as

> %{VARNAME}e   The contents of the environment variable VARNAME.

So the short answer is that "e" is short for "environment variable". For what that means exactly, follow the link and keep reading.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the link, i have found the variable format descriptions (in the link).